# Uploading file to local Eclipse folder

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am trying to get the basics of I/O with Spring.

I am working through the File Upload samples. I want to store the files in a temporary folder in the project for testing.

I have this code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, 
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
                //get directory

                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
```

I have created folder `"files"` within the project files. I want to know how to target the local folder.

I have tried using class `File`'s alternate constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to write files in external(from web container) directory is to use the full direct path to the file. Just use the full file path in following File constructor.

```
File(String pathname)
```

> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string
>   into an abstract pathname.

Comment: Further question, what if I want to temporarily store it in the web container